# A transistor switch

Tags: transistors

I asked a similar question yesterday, but this is still bugging me. I'm doing a "learn at home course DVD" and cannot figure out if this is correct or not. A lot of factors are being ignored because this is early on.

The issue is that this is the example, then there is a question with new numbers and I cannot get the correct answer using the method here.

[image]

Comment: Not sure where you're confusion is coming from.  The shaded box shows the calculations, which part are you having trouble with?  You could argue that to be sure the transistor is in saturation over variations in parameters you would want more base current, but the idea is there.  Not sure why the bulb isn't connected to the end of collector terminal, but the idea is there.  I think it's just poorly drawn.

Comment: @JohnD thanks for the reply. I fixed the image. I actually drew the image and typed up the text and such. I was wondering, is that completely correct? because the question asks to find R when: beta is 150, battery voltage is 24V, and light bulb draws 500mA. The answer given is 5.8k Ohms. I've tried for the last two days+ to get that answer, and can't (and neither could others in my last post.) So I was wondering if at least the example showed the correct approach and maybe the answer in the book was wrong.

Comment: So, which answer does your automated textbook show? As I recall, people advised you to get a better textbook if it does not show 11.3K

Comment: @EvanCarslake What you write in your comment is _very_ important for helping you. Your question shows a circuit and calculations, all of which are correct. There's no actual question.

Comment: Actually, the question seems to be "How can a BJT help?", which does not imply or ask for any calculations. Maybe this is a sort of exercise in understanding English, and requires an answer in a form of multiple choice? ;-)

Comment: @pipe I was wondering if everything in the image looked correct. Because the same book asked a question with the exact circuit only changing a few numbers and I cannot reach the solution.

Comment: @Ali Chen yeah, I would like to change courses, but this cost north of $400, and has a near 100 5 star ratings, from a series: The Great Courses... this is still bugging me even today.

Comment: It sounds like a big rip-off. Why don't you go to Radio Shack and get an introductory book for $1.50 or something?

Comment: Just because _one_ answer is off doesn't mean the course is crap. My copy of The Art of Electronics, 3rd edition, has an extensive [errata](http://artofelectronics.net/errata/), but you don't throw it in the trash because of that.

Comment: which particular item from The Great Courses are you enjoying? A brief visit to the http://www.thegreatcourses.com/ gives an impression of a scam publishing house, nothing about everything. No Horowitz and Hill there.

Comment: 5800 Ohms is almost exactly 20% higher current than the "correct " answer - Why I know not. | Ib = Ic/Beta = 500 /150 = 3.333 mA. |  Rb = Vr/Ir. = (24-0.7 say) / 3.333 mA = (23.3/0.00333) = 76990 Ohms. | 6990/5800 = 1.2(05). | In practice you design for substantially more Ib than expected to be needed at nominal Ib to make sure it works in reality.

Comment: @AliChen https://www.thegreatcoursesplus.com/understanding-modern-electronics taught by Richard Wolfson, Ph.D.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Why there should be exactly 20% guardband, when typical beta varies from 60 to 250, or 4X? Especially in introductory educational course?

Comment: The nub of the problem has arrived. You can't debate with a DVD course. It doesn't interact. Which is why an actual course at an actually university may be worth the trouble. Or a meetup group on electronics as a hobby, at the very least.

Comment: @jonk Agree. . ie I was not intending to say it was good or right - just that 20% looks like it happened for reasons unknown. That assumes Vbe = 0.7V. 0.6 or 0.8 give a less tidy ratio.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I was just smiling about this whole process, mostly. Not addressing you, in particular. But I think this kind of thing also, in some ways I suppose, points out part of why EE.SE exists and is valuable. To help make up for books and courses with which a _student_ or hobbyist cannot interact.

Comment: This is interesting, the course is taught by a professor who also teaches Climate Change in Middlebury's Environmental Studies Program. This might explain the accuracy of examples.

Comment: @Russell,why must the design include more Ib than needed and how much more is needed exactly?

Comment: @DanielTork The Global Circulation Models (GCMs)  include allowances for senstiivity enhancers -  forcing factors and feedbacks which take the basic Arrhenius equation which gives ~= a 1 degree C of temperture rise for a doubling of CO2 in isolation. Aspects such as the role of water vapour, inclusion of cloud models , CO2 residency before geologic capture, solubility, urban heat islands, localised or uni-hemispheric or global mediaeval warm period, affect of solar emissions on aerosols and thus cloud fornation and albedo modification .... Bzzzzzzzzzt  - OH. You mean his other subject!. Later